# Send Email from amazon ec2 instance

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, sendmail, amazon-ses

I have installed ubuntu on my ec2 instance. I want to send email using php from the website im hosting on this machine. I have tried SES and sent a successful email using console.  How can i do this? What is the easiest way (requiring least setup) ? What is the best way?

Comment: i have tried sendmail. it says sent without any error but email isnt sent. i have not tried anything else because i dont know how to. can you help?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you, I am just trying to help you improve your quality so other people might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

SES is a good idea. You have the option of either sending through SMTP or through the Amazon AWS SES API.

For sending trough SMTP you can use something like PHP Mailer:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

For sending through the SES API, look at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-ses.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail

The key thing to consider here, is that as with any email sending app, the deliverability of email is the tricky part, not the sending. 
SES has the concept of a sandbox where you can only send to/from verified emails/domains. It also collects metrics on how you are doing (bounces etc) and will take corrective actions if you use the service for spam. The upside of this, is that the odds of the mail being delivered are higher when it comes from SES as opposed to if you were to run your own mail server.

Comment: Thank you ! The problem is that im new to this so all this documentation looks like gibberish to me. Is there a ses setup guide for beginners ? I have already verified two emails as im in sandbox and have successfully sent email from console. now i want to send from php file on server. can you help me by explaining the steps in simple layman language please. please help me

Comment: the first link shows you how to send email via SMTP. you just have to just provide the server and the credentials: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-send-using-smtp.html

Comment: for API you basically need to learn how to use the AWS SDK and after that you just need to call sendemail. For API, most usage boils down to: build client, call method on client (this also applies for other AWS service)

Comment: i asked a friend to help. he uninstalled sendmail and installed sudo apt-get install php-pear   ||

sudo pear install mail  ||

sudo pear install Net_SMTP ||

sudo pear install Auth_SASL ||
sudo pear install mail_mime || and it worked. dont know how. even he doesnt , he read it somewhere on the internet. anyways thx for all the answers